# Get current Exchange Server

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm using EMS. When invoking **Get-ExchangeServer** command I'm getting list of available Exchange servers.

Now the question:

How to get current Exchange server (the one I've invoked **Get-ExchangeServer** command on)?

Can anyone advice how to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the environment variable `$ENV:COMPUTERNAME` to retrieve the server name of the exchange server that you are invoking the command on.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Exchange.domain.com `
               -ScriptBlock {Get-ExchangeServer -Identity $ENV:COMPUTERNAME} `
               -Credential (Get-Credential)
```

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about using `$ENV:COMPUTERNAME` before, but I was doing it in remote PS session and it returns my local computer name in this case. But you pointed me to right direction (i.e. using `Invoke-Command` to get value of `$ENV:COMPUTERNAME` on remote Exchange server and then use it when invoking `Get-ExchangeServer`). Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

- Short Answer:

  `Get-ExchangeServer | select PSComputerName,OriginatingServer -Unique`
- Explanation (Long Answer):

  The output of the command `Get-ExchangeServer`, already have the members that you are interested in :

```
PS:\ > Get-ExchangeServer | Get-Member

Name                    MemberType     (my explanation)
----                    ----------     -----------------
.                       .              .
PSComputerName          NoteProperty   It's the current ExchangeServer (the one that actually your command has been executed on)
OriginatingServer       Property       It's the current DomainController (the one that your ExchangeServer has used for the query)
.                       .              .
```

Then, using EMS or PSRemoting, It always returns what you want. however, the output may include multiple rows with the same value if you have more than one ExchangeServer in your environment. like :

```
PS:\ > Get-ExchangeServer | select PSComputerName,OriginatingServer

PSComputerName OriginatingServer      
-------------- -----------------      
exch-srv2      dc3.contoso.com
exch-srv2      dc3.contoso.com
.              .
```

that's why you can use `-unique` while doing `Select`, to avoid duplicate rows within the output.

```
PS:\ > Get-ExchangeServer | select PSComputerName,OriginatingServer -Unique

PSComputerName OriginatingServer      
-------------- -----------------      
exch-srv2      dc3.contoso.com
```